# Django LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL does not work with "next" request parameter

Tags: django, url, redirect, authentication

Django 1.11.3
The documentation about LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL says that:

> The URL where requests are redirected after login when the
>   contrib.auth.login view gets no next parameter.

I have LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL="some_url" in setting.py
I see "next=" (no value, just the key) in the request url when I login, so I suspect that makes Django to ignore LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL and I end up on Admin default page.
I use default login Django functionality, no custom template or anything. How do I get rid of "`next=`" in my request when I login (completely, no key) to see if LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL will be actually used (hopefully) ?

Comment: how do you get to the login view? Normally the `next` parameter is added when you're trying to access a view for which login is required (e.g. using the `LoginRequiredMixin` on a CBV). If you just have a login button you should direct it to the login url without `next`.

Comment: @dirkgroten I hit mydomain.com . No subpath. That hits ```url(r'^$', myview)```. that view has ```@login_required decorator```. That redirects me to login view since I am not logged in. After submitting my credentials I start dragging around ```"next="``` with no value in the request.  That I believe breaks LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL functionality

Answer (score 2):

That’s expected behavior. Normally you want the user requesting any view requiring login (with the `@login_required` decorator) to be redirected to that same view after login. This is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)

Since your view url is empty (the home url) you get `next=`. It’s quite uncommon to have a login required on the home page, from a user perspective it means you can’t see what you're signing up for.

If you remove the `@login_required` decorator for your view and just add a login button on your homepage (that goes to the regular `LoginView`) it will not have the `next` parameter and your users will be redirected to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` as expected.

Now, if really want users to have to login on your homepage and be redirected to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, you have two options:

- Remove the `@login_required` decorator and do the check and redirect in your view:

  ```
  from django.conf import settings

  def homepage(request):
      if not request.user.is_authenticated:
          return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
      # rest of view code
  ```
- If you're using class-based views, use the `LoginRequiredMixin` in your view and handle `handle_no_permission()` yourself:

  ```
  from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
  from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

  class Home(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

      def get(self):
           # your view code

      def handle_no_permission(self):
           # pass None to redirect_field_name in order to remove the next param
           return redirect_to_login(self.request.get_full_path(), self.get_login_url(), None)
  ```

Comment: Thank you but this did not help either. I remove ```@login_required``` from myform view in views.py,  added ```def homepage``` (if / else to go to LOGIN_URL for no auth users or LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL for auth'ed users), Also added  ```url(r'^$', homepage)``` to urls.py. Still getting to Admin portal after login. If I add   ```url(r'login', homepage)``` then when I hit ```mydomain.com``` in incognito window the LOGIN_URL case is executed but instead of login page I arrive directly to settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL page like I am always logged. BTW, "logout" goes to the same place.

Comment: what's your login URL? you realise you have to implement your own view (subclassing `LoginView` or writing your own) to add a login that's not the admin login? If your login view is the one from the admin site, you will always end up on the admin site. Or you can include the stock django urls (`include('django.contrib.auth.urls')`) which provide a login view in plain HTML.

Comment: Maybe it does not work the way I expected, just with settings and urls match and if/else redirect from a method in the view. I am trying to get it to work for both mydonaim.com and mydomain.com/login . Login view used is default from django admin, but the method that routes to LOGIN_URL and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL (depending on whether the user is auth'ed or not) works correctly WHEN CALLED. When I just log in, it's not called if I match with r'^$', r'', r'login' (login just routes directly to admin portal). Will research some more.

Comment: you should not use the admin login view for anything else than logging in admins. If your `/accounts/login` url shows your admin login then you're doing something wrong. Your app should have two login views: one for your users (which will behave the way I described if you use or subclass `LoginView`) and one for your admins (which will not behave this way, because it will always get you to the admin site).

Comment: Got it, will try. That was original implementation from before, just simpler.  Thanks a lot to you and @Sreeram, I feel I understand much better now how those pieces are connected even though it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in your settings.py, then in case you are not giving any next parameter to url, it will go to default url mentioned in LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL.

if LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'some/path/'

**https://yourdomain.com/login/** will redirect to 'some/path/'

**https://yourdomain.com/login/?next=/override/default/path** 
will redirect to 'override/default/path'

Comment: Well, that's what the docs say. What really happens is this:
I am hitting just mydomain.com . No subpath after that. 
It redirects me to: ```mydomain.com/login/login/?next=/admin/login/?next=/``` .
That loads login view, everyting is OK. When I enter login and password and submit, it calls ```mydomain.com/?next=``` . I think the mere presence of "next=" in the submitted request (even without value) throws it off and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL is ignored. So, that's what I am asking: now to clean it up, how to get rid of that ```"next="``` piece completely without overriding login and its templates?

Comment: as @dirkgroten clearly explained in the other answer, remove the LoginRequiredMixin(@login_required in case you are using a function) and check if user is authenticated. If not redirect to login page